# read and modify/update cell in datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, datatable

**Scenario**
I want to calculate and rank the suitability of healthcare workers for a particular patients, by comparing parameters such as race, religion, gender, spoken language, etc.

```
HealthcareWorker table
----------------------
ID (int)
name (varchar)
race (varchar)
religion (varchar)
gender (varchar)
german (bit)
french (bit)
english (bit)


Patient table
-------------
ID (int)
name (varchar)
race (varchar)
religion (varchar)
gender (varchar)
german (bit)
french (bit)
english (bit)
```

**Webpage Layout**
On `page1.aspx` there will be a `gridview` table showing the details of all `Patients`.
User will then select a `Patient` and be directed to `page2.aspx`

On `page2.aspx` there will a table showing the details of each `Healthcare Worker` and his suitability with the selected `patient` in the form of a `score`. there will also be `checkboxes` inside the table in order to assign more than one `Healthcare Worker` to the selected `Patient`.

```
page2.aspx
| ID |  name | religion | gender  |  german  |  french |  english |  score |          |
|----+-------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+--------+----------|
| 4  |  mary |          |    f    |    1     |    0    |    1     |   132  | checkbox |
| 2  |  john |          |    m    |    0     |    1    |    1     |   125  | checkbox |
| 3  |  tim  |          |    m    |    1     |    0    |    1     |    98  | checkbox |
| 1  |  jane |          |    f    |    1     |    1    |    0     |    55  | checkbox |
```

the computation of the score will be something like this:

```
if patient.race = healthcareworker.race then healthcarework.score +10
if patient.religion = healthcareworker.religion then healthcarework.score +10
if at least one of patient's language match with healthcareworker's language then healthcarework.score +10
```

code:

```
    Dim strCon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString1").ConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strCon)

    Dim query As String = "select *, CAST ( 0 as int ) score from HealthcareWorker;"

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, con)

    con.Open()

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.Load(dr)

    'code to read cell
    'code to compare and compute
    'code to update the score in each row

    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()

    con.Close()
```

How do I read and modify the cells in the datatable?
I want read and compare the data from some cells in each row and then update the `score` value.

I need to update the `score` for each row so I am going to need a loop but I do not know the number of rows that will be loaded into the `datatable` before hand.
How do I get the number of rows in the `datatable`?

edit/update: *reworked the entire question to provide (a lot) more background information*

Comment: Why don't you do it in the database? So replace `CAST ( 0 as int )` with the actual calculation. Apart from that, it's not clear at all how you want to calculate the score, `select *` is not helpful.

Comment: i am simplifying my actual scenario to make it easier to explain. don't worry about how i calculate the `score`. the `score` is more of a decision pairing matrix score rather than gaming score. the `score` is not stored in the db but calculated and stored on the fly because the `score` is only valid for the combination of values in a certain row in `table1` with another combination of values in another row in some other table.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you can't calculate it in the sql. You could use a for-loop or foreach-loop on table.Rows. But because I don't know the schema I cannot show an example. To access and cast the columns use row.Field.

Comment: reworked the entire question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last question is answered easily:

> I need to update the score for each row so I am going to need a loop
>   but I do not know the number of rows that will be loaded into the
>   datatable before hand. **How do I get the number of rows in the
>   datatable**?

You just have to use the [`Rows.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135388%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
Dim rowCount As Int32 = tblPatient.Rows.Count ' tblPatient => DataTable '
```

If you want to loop all rows you can use a `foreach`:

```
For Each row As DataRow In tblPatient.Rows
    ' ... '
Next
```

or a `for`-loop:

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To tblPatient.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim row As DataRow = tblPatient.Rows(i)
    ' ... '
Next
```

To update the rows you can use the `SetField` extension method which also support nullable-types:

```
For Each row As DataRow In tblPatient.Rows
    Dim id As Int32 = row.Field(Of Int32)("ID")
    Dim race As String = row.Field(Of String)("Race")
    row.SetField("Score", CalculateScore(row))
Next
```

Sorry that i cannot provide you the correct calculation but it's still not clear how you want to calculate it since you haven't provided the source of the `Score`(theres no column). But it might give you an idea anyway.

Comment: thx, now I have an idea of what to do. for the sake of others who might be taking a looking at this, the `SetField` in the `For Each` loops does not work unless I add a `tblPatient.Columns("Score").ReadOnly = False` before the `loop`. somehow setting `readonly = false` in the .aspx does not work, it only works if it is done in the .aspx.vb